# Dynamically creating my meny in silverlight, I need to make the selected item highlighted

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a dynamically generated menubar, that is a control that i've built that holds a couple of textblocks, the menuitems is populated dependent on what role you have in the system. My problem now is that I need to make the selected menu item to change looks, so the user can see what tab he's on. Please give me some idees to how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your control it is hard to answer - however I generally find, in simplest terms, that adjusting the Opacity of the control is incredibly helpful. Try setting the Opacity of ALL the menuitems to .8 (80%) by default. Then when an item is pressed (or maybe hovered over) set the Opacity of that item to 1 (100%). You will see it brighten and the color deepen a bit. This makes it obvious that the item is "selected" without having to jump through a lot of hoops. This technique has the added benefit that you can extend it to buttons of different colors or even various images, and it will still "work".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answere! I can change the look easily with the mouse enter and leave event, but how should I handle the "active" state as it's called in the html world? Any idea?

Comment: Again, hard to say without seeing it. You have few options. The easiest and most common way is to just leave it set at the "hovered" state once selected. Boom, done. Otherwise, you can maybe set a thin border around it. Or increase it's size slightly. Or lower the two other opacity settings slightly, and then make "active" 100% opacity. Or display a checkmark icon over the item. Just be creative. :)